# Suspended Ubuntu 17.04 , when "wake up" does full reboot

Tags: suspend, asus, 17.04, lid, systemd-journald

After installing Ubuntu 17.04 a week ago on my `/dev/sda1` partition, all was working properly. 
Closing the lid **put my computer into suspend mode**. 
Opening it up, touching a keyboard touch turned it on, as expected.
I installed a set of packages and used it normally.

Then yesterday my chromium / computer freezed completely so I hard-rebooted it.

Ever since, right after the startup screen displaying the word "Ubuntu" upon purple background, there is a quick (1sec) white-on-black text screen message :

On Day one :

```
/dev/sda1: recovering journal
/dev/sda1: clean 202498/1525920 files, 1470005/6103515 blocks
```

On Day 2 (few reboots, no real usage nor pkg installations)

```
/dev/sda1: recovering journal
/dev/sda1: Clearing orphaned inode 130826 (uid=112, gid=118, node=0100644, size=2547)
/dev/sda1: Clearing orphaned inode 130837 (uid=112, gid=118, node=0100644, size=2547)
/dev/sda1: Clearing orphaned inode 130825 (uid=112, gid=118, node=0100644, size=2547)
/dev/sda1: Clearing orphaned inode 130834 (uid=112, gid=118, node=0100644, size=2547)
/dev/sda1: clean, 202523/1525920 files, 1478967/6103515 blocks
```

And, when I close the lid, **opening it back turns the PC on** (without pushing the button). I lose all running apps, my browser tabs, etc.

```
Test | Way to suspend   | Status                                   | Way to open                  | Result 
#1   | close the lid    | Suspended (lightbulb icon light=flashes) | Open the lid > press a touch | Reboots fully
#2   | (menu) > Suspend | Suspended (idem)                         | Press a touch                | Reboots fully
#3   | time goes        | Suspended (idem)                         | Press a touch                | Wake up with previous apps
```

**Any idea how I can solve this and get proper suspension via lid closing and Menu>Suspend ?**

---

PC: https://www.asus.com/Notebooks/K401UB/

```
Processor : Intel Core i7 6500U
OS: Ubuntu 17.04
Chipset : Integrated Intel® CPU 
Memory : DDR3L 1600 MHz SDRAM, OnBoard Memory 4 GB 
Graphic : NVIDIA® GeForce® 940M
```

Comment: Do you also have Windows on this machine? If so, does it work properly? Did you upgrade from a prior Ubuntu, or first Ubuntu install? What packages did you install? How much swap space? Are you aware of the CPU temps and fan usage? Also, see my partial answer, below.

Answer (score 3):

Lets first check your file system for errors.

To check the file system on your Ubuntu partition...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

Comment: Ok. First, before I tested your workflow : I plugged my pc on the wall to continue my tests and... the suspend thing works again (O.ô+weird+ok good!). Both while on wall OR on battery. I did **NO change, zero pkg installation, nothing, just 2 dozens tests of the suspend thing : lid closing, click "Menu > Suspend", wait for suspension, hard rebooting**.
I assume the issue will come back somedays soon. Indeed, first time was in 2 weeks ago with my first installation of Ubuntu 17.04, so I reformatted my whole hard-drive and reinstalled the current Ubuntu 17.04, which displayed the bug as well.

Comment: Note : I did +1 on your answer, but I need a reputation of 15 points so It shows up. I keep your answer ready for the next time it show up !

Comment: @HugoLOPEZ did you do the fsck? Did it come out OK?

Comment: Needs 15, must wait a bit. Main point is to thanks you :)

Comment: @Hugolpz You're welcome. Is it all working now?

Comment: Yes. Working ... for unknow reason.

Comment: 0
down vote
 

Worked for me! Thanks @heynnema

For the sake of completeness, I had the same problem (full reboot instead of wake up after suspending), and it also happened after a crash due to Chrome (Chromium does the same). But I didn't see the same messages as Hugo.

Note that "sudo" is not required in the recovery root shell.