# The PC restarts after Ubuntu shut down

Tags: grub2, shutdown, reboot

I have an Acer Aspire V571G with i3 and 6GB RAM. I installed on SSD both Windows and Ubuntu in Legacy mode.

My Ubuntu 17.04 (previous 16.10 and 16.04) shows the same problem. I shut down the system and it seems to be all right: The PC goes off but after a few seconds it reboots itself and shows the GRUB. Windows shuts down correctly. What kind of problem could be?

Comment: Does the same thing happen when you shutdown from Windows?

Comment: No, Windows shuts down correctly. I read about a BIOS setting, wake on LAN, that could be the problem?

Comment: Wake-on-lan packets merely wake/resume a (properly configured) suspended machine. They cannot magically boot a powered-off machine. Does the reboot include POST (the manufacturer logo)?

Comment: Yes, the reboot includes the ACER logo. And then shows up grub

Comment: Do you have any hints for me?

Comment: Check your BIOS settings, particularly what-to-do upon power loss. Your particular BIOS may have such settings, some do - some don't. A reboot-instead-of-shutdown from Ubuntu would not include the ACER logo - Ubuntu seems to be telling the hardware to poweroff. Strange.

Comment: I checked BIOS settings: there is no ”power loss" voice. What can I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Suspended Ubuntu 17.04 , when "wake up" does full reboot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/906979/suspended-ubuntu-17-04-when-wake-up-does-full-reboot)